# Making an elasticsearch nested query for match on all fields of nested object

Tags: elasticsearch

The basic question is as follows:
Is there a convenient way to specify a multi-field match on all fields for a nested query?
For a normal query `{ match : { _all : "query string" }}` works.
This doesn't work in a nested query for perhaps because the nested object doesn't have an _all?

The more detailed question below:

I have a nested document called "Parent" as follows:

```
{
    "children" : [
        { 
            "field_a": "value_a_1",
            "field_b" : "value_b_1",
            "field_c" : [ {
                "field_c_a" : "value_c_a_1",
                "field_c_b" : "value_c_b_1"
            } ]
        },
        { 
            "field_a": "value_a_2",
            "field_b" : "value_b_2",
            "field_c" : [ {
                "field_c_a" : "value_c_a_2",
                "field_c_b" : "value_c_b_2"
            } ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the mapping I used for making the children nested objects:

```
"Parent" : {
    "properties" : {
        "children" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "include_in_parent" : true
                }
    }
}
```

And here is a query, where I want to select a few terms using a match on all children fields query, and a term query:

```
"query" : {
    "nested": { 
        "path" : "children",
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                        {"multi_match" : {"query": "value_c_a_1", "fields" : ["children.*"]}},
                        {"term" : {children.field_a : "value_a_1" }}
                    ]
                }
            }
    } 
}
```

The above query doesn't work because I can't select all fields in a multimatch query for a nested object.

```
"query" : {
    "nested": { 
        "path" : "children",
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                        {"multi_match" : {"query": "value_c_a_1", "fields" : ["*_c_a"]}}
                    ]
                }
            }
    } 
}
```

The query above works because the pattern matching allows a * to be placed before a string but not after for some reason (?)

**Is there a nice shorthand way to select all the fields of a nested object?**

It would also be nice to know why the expected children.* wildcard doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Worked normally for me (note: Elasticsearch 1.7). Notice the different names though (aparent, somechildren) - I haven't tested it with the original names, but it could have something to do with it.

Schema:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "aparent": {
      "properties": {
        "somechildren": {
          "type": "nested",
          "include_in_parent": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Document:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/aparent/1 -d '{
  "somechildren" : [
    {
      "field_a": "value_a_1",
      "field_b" : "value_b_1",
      "field_c" : [ {
        "field_c_a" : "value_c_a_1",
        "field_c_b" : "value_c_b_1"
      } ]
    },
    {
      "field_a": "value_a_2",
      "field_b" : "value_b_2",
      "field_c" : [ {
        "field_c_a" : "value_c_a_2",
        "field_c_b" : "value_c_b_2"
      } ]
    }
  ]
}'
```

Query:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "somechildren",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "value_c_a_1",
                "fields": [
                  "somechildren.*"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "somechildren.field_a": {
                  "value": "value_a_1"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
  {
     "took": 2,
     "timed_out": false,
     "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
     },
     "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0.8603305,
        "hits": [
           {
              "_index": "test",
              "_type": "aparent",
              "_id": "1",
              "_score": 0.8603305,
              "_source": {
                 "somechildren": [
                    {
                       "field_a": "value_a_1",
                       "field_b": "value_b_1",
                       "field_c": [
                          {
                             "field_c_a": "value_c_a_1",
                             "field_c_b": "value_c_b_1"
                          }
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "field_a": "value_a_2",
                       "field_b": "value_b_2",
                       "field_c": [
                          {
                             "field_c_a": "value_c_a_2",
                             "field_c_b": "value_c_b_2"
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  }
```